# Timing my php function with using Result cache and without result cache

Tags: php, symfony, redis, doctrine, profiling

I have been trying to measure the time taken by one of my php functions when it is using result cache and when it is not using it.

I am having trouble as whichever is run first in result will give more time, hence the results are not conclusive.

Here is a part of my code -

```
     /**
     *
     * @param InputInterface $input
     * @param OutputInterface $output
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
//        $this->withoutCache($output);
        $this->withCache($output);
        $this->withoutCache($output);
    }
```

OUTPUT -

```
RUN 1 - 
withoutCache: 0.10952067375183
withCache: 0.077319145202637

RUN 2 - 
withCache: 0.17031812667847
withoutCache: 0.042220115661621
```

I am using symfony framework and I am testing if using caching will help me very much in case of each query. Symfony is using Doctrine ORM with redis as Result Cache.

Answer (score 0):

You might be initializing some objects or do some other works that is not relevant to the actual process that is why the 1st one always takes more time.

Before doing benchmarking kind of tests.

1. Make sure all the objects are created and you only measure the time taken for the actual process.
2. Also try run them in a multi threaded environment to get the optimal numbers.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The first run always need to initialize the connection to the db, thus more time to process. After that all subsequents queries will use the same connection. To verify create a loop where you run multiple times your test.